# IIS custom header "Content-Security-Policy" is overwritten

Tags: iis, sharepoint, content-security-policy, response-headers

I have currently an issue with a SharePoint web application, where all websites return a response header `content-security-policy: default-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; form-action 'self'`, which breaks the website's view using Chrome or Firefox, as styles won't be applied and Javascript won't be executed.

**Console-Log**

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: `default-src 'self'`.
>   Either the `'unsafe-inline'` keyword, a hash (`'sha256-WFRyoBrQbrYtLpGIdyBszDzxQni3b0V/wUirab0OhKM='`), or a nonce (`'nonce-...'`) is required to enable inline execution.
>   Note also that `'script-src'` was not explicitly set, so `'default-src'` is used as a fallback.

The problems only occurs if the websites are addressed using HTTPS. I already checked the HTTP Response Headers in IIS. `content-security-policy` is not specified. If I add it myself, it gets overwritten and is not sent in the response header. There are only two solutions installed, which do not mess with the response headers.

Has anyone an idea what else could change the custom response header and overwrite the one defined in the *web.config*? Or is there an other way to change the Content-Security-Policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested changing the IIS Response Headers by configuring the "CustomHeaders"-section in the web.config, by writing custom IIS modules, which modified the headers using the request lifecycle, and also by writing additional rules with the URL Rewriting tool. Nothing worked...

In the end we found out someone extended the firewall, which onwards would add new header and overwrite my changes of the HTTPS response. Mystery solved :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was asked by Network and Information Security Team to add the **Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self';** header in my IIS 8.5 SharePoint Server 2016 Publishing website which affects all the system pages and the browser refuses to execute the scripts and in console we got this error

**Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-HU8dCwZsqh4m8QG0y6qanyzPx1d6YSGHuAN0QXmxZvw='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.**

I then change the header to **Content-Security-Policy:frame-ancestors 'self';** and it resolves the issue.

I actually got this from the [JohnC's Answer that helps me resolving the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992225/config-your-iis-server-to-use-the-content-security-policy-header#:%7E:text=Add%20a%20comment-,10,on%20their%20Content%20Security%20Policy%20Cheat%20Sheet%20under%20Preventing%20Clickjacking%3A,-To%20prevent%20all)

[image: SharePOint 2016 Publishing site after adding Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; custom header]