# Fixing "Missing or insecure Content-Security-Policy header" vulnerability in back-end services in Linux

Tags: linux, apache, security, httpd.conf, content-security-policy

I have a set of *Python* back-end services deployed in a Linux box.
I found the "**Missing or insecure Content-Security-Policy header**" vulnerability in them using *IBM AppScan*. Which suggests `Configure your server to use the "Content-Security-Policy" header with secure policies`.

I tried to resolve the issue by adding a `Content-Security-Policy` header in `httpd.conf` file as below, but none of them are working.

I tired all these combinations:

```
1> Header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors xxx.xx.xxx.115"
2> Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'"
3> Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'"
```

This will be helpful if anyone can provide me some solution to resolve this issue.

---

I was referring the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/40248391.