# Content Security Policy blocks Angular Styles

Tags: angular, content-security-policy, unsafe-inline

I want to publish a web application with a strict Content Security Policy.  The last remaining issue is: `style-src 'self';`

I get an error in the browser console saying that a resource was blocked from loading based on the style-src directive in the CSP.  The error references code in the main..js file that is produced from `ng build --prod`.

If I add `'unsafe-inline'` to the `style-src` directive in the CSP, everything works fine, however, I do not want to do this.

Is there anything I can do in my code or build option to make the web application work with the more restrictive CSP?

I was using Angular 11 and just upgraded to 12 and have the same error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

#### Options for resolution:

### 1. Use SHA-256 hashes

If there is a relatively small amount of such violations, you can add their hashes.
Example, if you see this in your log:

```
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'report-sample'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-YpcdPia2p132TdnpnY8zwrWWSqByEKGZBY5iqsLBkSg='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.
```

Add `'sha256-YpcdPia2p132TdnpnY8zwrWWSqByEKGZBY5iqsLBkSg='`
You may also need `'unsafe-hashes'` - depending on the context.
**Note: This approach is not easy to sustain. A small change in a style will force you to recreate the hash.** It's useful only when you have a handful of such inline scripts.

### 2. Nonces

You can use nonces to "bless" inline styles and approve them. However, even [Google experts who advocate for CSP nonces](https://web.dev/strict-csp/) don't usually deploy them on `style-src` - only on `script-src`.
**Note: This approach is hard to deploy.** A unique nonce needs to be generated for every pageload.

### 3. Use `'unsafe-inline'` - it's fine for `style-src` (not great for `script-src`)

Really, even setting a CSP with
`style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' someurl.com;` is much safer than 99.9% of sites. More than [accounts.google.com](https://accounts.google.com/) that does not restrict `style-src` at all.
[Github](https://github.com) have a fantastic high quality CSP with `style-src: 'unsafe-inline'`

#### Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

> If I add `'unsafe-inline'` to the `style-src` directive in the CSP, everything works fine, however, I do not want to do this.

Looks like that's impossible at the moment. According to Angular's support thread at Github, an [allowing 'unsafe-inline' in style-src is required for Angular applications](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37631) (have a look at "Suggested Steps" 1. "We should clearly state that allowing 'unsafe-inline' in style-src is required for Angular applications.").

Answer (score 0):

Update for Angular 16: you can now provide a CSP_NONCE token and it will apply that nonce to any CSS added by Angular. The nonce will just need to match the one from your Content Security Policy.

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [{
    provide: CSP_NONCE,
    useValue: globalThis.myRandomNonceValue
  }]
});
```

https://angular.io/guide/security#content-security-policy