# Content Security Policy directive: Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash, or a nonce is required

Tags: angular, firebase, content-security-policy, websecurity

I am setting security headers for the firebase project, one of them is `Content-Security-Policy`. The value of it is like this now:

```
default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';font-src 'self' https: data:;form-action 'self';frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;object-src 'none';script-src 'self';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';upgrade-insecure-requests
```

Since we have scripts that are executed in the index.html file, one of the issues is with the `script-src` property. It throws the following error now:

```
it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash, or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution
```

I researched the `unsafe-inline`, `unsafe-eval`, etc and I found that it's better to not use them. So I am not sure how to solve the issue. Could you please advise?

Comment: Looks like a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68459561/content-security-policy-blocks-angular-styles